# Javascript onbeforeunload Survey

Tags: javascript, forms, onbeforeunload, survey

I'm trying to get a survey to show when a user tries to close the browser/page tab. The ideal scenario is that upon the user closing the tab or browser. Either a popup window is triggered, or an internal page popup.

The issues I have encountered after research are internal links and page refreshes will trigger a page leave, and also I haven't found an option that doesn't use an alert message.

Is it possible to determine the type of page leave (e.g. closed tab or browser) and is it possible to trigger the survey popup or new window without a page alert in the javascript.

Any help on this would be great as it seems a lot of people are stuck in the same position without a definitive answer.

Comment: My thought process: "Hmm, this was a somewhat interesting site, but I need to get back to wo-" -exit-blocking popup requesting I take a survey- "NOPE **** YOU I'M NEVER COMING BACK!" Seriously, don't stop a person from leaving. Ever. Unless it's obvious it may be an accident, such as when they've started typing a post.

Comment: Sadly that isn't an option here as this is a request from higher so it has to be done.

Comment: Ouch. It's a shame higher powers seem oblivious to the ways of the real world... To provide a less sarcastic answer, no, there is no way to tell if a user is leaving your site or just going to another page of it.

Comment: I know you can disable the function upon clicking internal links which is fine, but not ideal.